# Timoshenko beam bilinear form non-negative

Tags: functional-analysis, classical-mechanics, bilinear-form, finite-element-method

The Timoshenko beam theory yields the following variational problem.
For $t\in(0,1), f\in L_2$ given, we search for a $(w,\beta)\in V\subset[H^1(0,1)]^2$ such that it is a solution of

> \begin{align*}
> A((w,\beta),(v,\delta))
> :=
>  \int\limits_{0}^1 \beta'\delta'dx+ \frac{1}{t^2}\int\limits_0^1(w'-\beta)(v'-\delta)dx 
>  = \int\limits_0^1 f v dx \ \forall(v,\delta)\in V
> \end{align*}
>
> I want to prove that the bilinear form $A((w,\beta),(v,\delta))$ is non-negative.

Does anyone know how to do this? I think it might be possible by using Young's inequality.

Comment: In your context, is a bilinear form said to be "non-negative" if $A(x,x)\geq 0$ for all $x$? If so, you want to prove that $A((w,\beta),(w,\beta))\geq 0$ for all $(w,\beta)\in V$, right? Well, what is $A((w,\beta),(w,\beta))$?

Comment: I need $A((w,\beta),(v,\delta)) \geq 0$. The non-negativ condition is needed to apply Tartars theorem. You can find it here : https://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~schoeberl/wiki/lva/numpde18/numpde.pdf at page 39 Theorem 50. This will allow me to show that the bilinear form is coercive.

Comment: With your definition of non-negative, $A$ isn't non-negative. For example: if $\beta,v$ are functions in $H^1$ such that $\beta>0$ and $v'>0$, then  $A((0,\beta),(v,0))<0$.

Comment: Thank you Pedro! I think I missunderstood the definition of non-negative, but now it's clear what is meant. Also the estimate by Hölder inequality is very usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my comment, $A$ is non-negative because
$$A((w,\beta),(w,\beta))=\|\beta'\|_{L^2}^2 +\frac{1}{t^2}\|w'-\beta\|^2_{L^2}\geq 0,\quad\forall \ (w,\beta)\in V.$$

I suspect that you want to prove that $A$ is $V$-continuous. If so, you should use the [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality):

Since 
$$A((w,\beta),(v,\delta))
= \int\limits_{0}^1 \beta'\delta'\;dx+ \frac{1}{t^2}\int\limits_0^1(w'v'-w'\delta-\beta v'+\beta\delta)\;dx,$$
we have
\begin{align*}
|A((w,\beta),(v,\delta))|
&\leq \int\limits_{0}^1 |\beta'||\delta'|\;dx+ \frac{1}{t^2}\int\limits_0^1|w'||v'|+|w'||\delta|+|\beta||v'|+|\beta||\delta|\;dx
\end{align*}
and thus, by Hölder's inequality,
\begin{align*}
|A((w,\beta),(v,\delta))|
&\leq \|\beta'\|_{L^2}\|\delta'\|_{L^2}+\frac{1}{t^2}\left(\|w'\|_{L^2}\|v'\|_{L^2}+\|w'\|_{L^2}\|\delta\|_{L^2}+\|\beta\|_{L^2}\|v'\|_{L^2}+|\beta\|_{L^2}\|\delta\|_{L^2}\right)\\
&\leq \frac{1}{t^2}\left(\|\beta'\|_{L^2}\|\delta'\|_{L^2}+\|w'\|_{L^2}\|v'\|_{L^2}+\|w'\|_{L^2}\|\delta\|_{L^2}+\|\beta\|_{L^2}\|v'\|_{L^2}+|\beta\|_{L^2}\|\delta\|_{L^2}\right).
\end{align*}
Note that
$\|\beta'\|^2_{L^2}\leq\|\beta\|_{H^1}^2\leq \|(w,\beta)\|_V^2$ and thus $\|\beta'\|_{L^2}\leq \|(w,\beta)\|_V$. A similar estimate is valid for the other terms. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|A((w,\beta),(v,\delta))|
&\leq \frac{5}{t^2}\|(w,\beta)\|_V\|(v,\delta)\|_V.
\end{align*}